# iOS push notification aps-environment is always set to production instead of development

Tags: ios, push-notification, entitlements

I know similar questions have been asked here, but I did not found a solution to my problem.

I have an iOS project using push notifications. I would like to test this capability in development mode.

The server I use to send notification is configured for sandbox.
When I try to push a notification, the sandbox send me an error message : Bad Device token !

I created a development provisioning profile.

I created a development push certificat.

I created the entitlement file in my iOS project with the value APS Environment = development
The application is build with ad hoc.

When I generate a new application, in the later box, Xcode changes the APNS entitlements to production. I think the problem is here, 'production' instead of 'development', but why this change ? All my certificates, profiles, entitlement are setting with development !
How can I force entitlement to development ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sandbox APNS on AdHoc Distribution Builds for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240931/using-sandbox-apns-on-adhoc-distribution-builds-for-ios)